Can lawyers perform actions for the sole purpose of delay if the client is facing the death penalty?
This answer contains the remark:

Lawyers are also officers of the court and are specifically prohibited from taking actions in litigation with the sole purpose of delay. (The analysis would be different if Trump were facing the death penalty.)

The implication is the in the death penalty were at stake, the answer might be different. Is that correct? Is it a just different ethical situation, a different legal situation, or both?

In lieu of a full answer that I may post later, if I have time, here is are links to two law review article on the professional ethical issues particular to death penalty defense. https://ir.lawnet.fordham.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1869&context=faculty_scholarship and https://repository.law.miami.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1205&context=fac_articles&httpsredir=1&referer=
